# SSIS XML Create Variables for Excel Destination (Sheet Creation)

Tags: xml, ssis

I am just becoming familiar with SSIS. We have very large XML files to process and I have successfully exported data from the XML files into a Excel Template I created using Excel Destination step in SSIS. The top elements are mapped to the worksheets created in the excel Template file. Most of the time the XML structure is the same however I have just come to realise there maybe some elements missing and the flow I created now fails for those XML files. Ideally I don't want to have different flows for the different XML files.

What I thought I might be able to do was use XPATH to test if elements are there with the XML task, create variables and send those variables flowing through to the XML source step and then on to the Excel Destination step. So a more dynamic approach. So in essence read XML file, check XML elements, and set variables based on the results and then use those variables to create the Worksheets in the Excel file.

However, with all my reading and looking at SO Threads im not sure if this is possible with the prebuilt SSIS toolbox steps.

Has anyone managed to do something similar? Or am I looking at a full scripted solution in SSIS using the scripting task? Or another method?

Many thanks I really appreciate it.

Comment: You can try to use SSIS XML Task, operation XSLT Transformation to reshape problematic XML files into expected format.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky OK awesome many thanks ill look into it further. thx very much.